# How to easily tell which PPAs need to be purged

Tags: apt, gnome, ppa

I have several PPAs, such as the Fresh Libre Office one, and the GNOME3 Staging one, and this means that I get all of the latest packages, however a lot of these PPAs in the descriptions say that you should use `ppa-purge` on them before doing a system upgrade. Now as the release of 15.10 is coming rather soon, and I am currently running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04, I will be needing to purge some of my PPAs rather soon, but as I have quite a few PPAs I don't know which will need it (other than the two that I already mentioned), the only thing that I do know is that all of those PPAs that will need `ppa-purge` to be used on them have the String `ppa-purge` in their PPA description.

So is there a simple script or something which can check all the PPA descriptions of all the PPAs installed on my system and report back to me which of those have the String `ppa-purge` in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That string containing `ppa-purge` does not mean anything special.

It is recommended to disable all PPA before you upgrade a release.
It is even **better** to purge all PPA.

Otherwise some dependency problems may occur and the system will not be upgraded properly.

Ubuntu developers do not test compatibility of PPA and system upgrades. You install software from PPA at your own risk.

It is possible to write a script that will check descriptions for `ppa-purge`, but it makes no sense.